# What does the $I$ mean in Tensor notation?

Tags: notation, real-numbers, tensors

I'm quite new to tensors.
I notice many math sources show a tensor, T, in this way for example:

$$ T \in \mathbb{R}^{I_{1} \times I_{2} \times \ldots \times I_{N} \times K}$$

I believe that $I$ is a dimension, but I'm unsure if it means anything more significant such as an identity...

since we have $N$ $I$'s do all $N$ $I$'s have to be the same size?

For example, if $I = 50$ could the above tensor T have dimensions (50,50,10) and then we'd write it as

$$ T \in \mathbb{R}^{50 \times 50 \times 10}?$$

Comment: Please cite a specific reference. I can conjecture an answer to your question, but I can't be definitive without knowing what sources you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols with subscripts usually don't relate in any particular way to their "unsubscripted" versions; the subscript is just part of the name. So (unless the author has specified otherwise) an expression involving $I_1,I_2$, etc. doesn't refer to something named $I$ at all. In your example, it looks like the $I_n$ are just numbers with related names - nothing about the notation indicates that they need to have the same value.